# How to add custom post meta to default blog post?

Tags: php, actions

I have a code which calculates estimated reading time of a blog post *(feel free to use it as you wish)*:

```
function estimated_reading_time( $post ) {

    $words = str_word_count( strip_tags( $post->post_content ) );

    //Average reading speed of an adult is 200-250 words per minute
    $minutes = floor( $words / 200 );
    $seconds = floor( $words % 200 / ( 200 / 60 ) );

    //At least a minute
    if ( $minutes >= 1 ) {

        $estimated_time = $minutes . ' minute' . ( $minutes == 1 ? '' : 's' ) . ', ' . $seconds . ' second' . ( $seconds == 1 ? '' : 's' );
    } 
    //Less than a minute
    else {

        $estimated_time = $seconds . ' second' . ($seconds == 1 ? '' : 's');
    }

    return $estimated_time;
}
```

**Problem:** This function is suitable for the page generating loop however it is unnessesary to run this function for every blog post in every page load in a blog. It would be smarter to save it as post meta.

---

**Question:** How to save `$estimated_time` as post meta to WordPress default blog post?

Are there any actions, hooks or callbacks that I could use in `functions.php` or in a plugin?

PS! It should save the value when post is created and also when it's edited later on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the action hook `save_post_{post_type}`, so for the post type 'post' (blog posts) it is: `save_post_post`. For more info see the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post).

```
add_action( 'save_post_post', 'sw150216_save_reading_time', 10, 3);

function sw150216_save_reading_time( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    $reading_time = estimated_reading_time( $post );
    if ( $update ) {
        update_post_meta ( $post_id, 'reading_time', $reading_time );
    } else {
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'reading_time', $reading_time, true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)?  You should.

Comment: Seriously?  It states "triggered whenever a post or page is created or update".  There are even examples of how to handle custom posts types.

Comment: There is the hook `save_post_{post_type}`, so `save_post_post` is just for the post-type 'post' (blog post).

Comment: I updated my code for blog posts

Comment: @N00b OK, you win. The second example shows specifically how to deal with custom post types. With a little thought that code makes it clear what to do (or not do) when ANY particular post type come along.  I'm not trying to write code for you but to point out resources that will allow you to do it yourself.  If you give a man a fish you feed him for a day.

Answer (score 0):

Hook your function to `save_post`.  Use `add_post_meta` to add the field for a new post or update if this is an edit.  See the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) for adding vs. updating custom fields.